# add a custom page file into the menu

Tags: php

Ok i have a file which named,

```
page-allpost.php
```

now I have a menu item called "all post" and in that menu I want to call the page-allpost.php which will display all the post. how to do that?

hope someone here could help, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this by

`include('file path')` or `include_once('file path')`

or `require('file path')` or `require_once('file path')`

difference between include and require

> The difference is that if we use require_once() then the file to be added should exist in the given path,if not it will display a fatal error.if we use a include_once there will be no more problem due to this ,if there exist no such file.if we need to include a file then we will prefer include_once() because it will include the file once,it willnot include the file if it is inluded earlier

when use require or include

> Unlike include(), require() will always read in the target file, even if the line it's on never executes. If you want to conditionally include a file, use include(). The conditional statement won't affect the require(). However, if the line on which the require() occurs is not executed, neither will any of the code in the target file be executed.

Comment: perhaps you dont get it clearly, all i want is to link the page-allpost.php into the "all post" menu item so whenever a user click the "all post" menu item, then they will rediect into this http://thesite.com/news/ and that one "news" is from "page-allpost.php"

Answer (score 0):

OK, i just add a name to my template header and then link it to the custom page and then add the page into the menu and thats it, everything work as i expected.